# Streaming and recording video with authentication in a Cordova app

Tags: android, ios, cordova, streaming, ip-camera

I'm making a Cordova app for Android and iOS which needs to embed and record streaming video from an IP camera. I'm testing with a D-Link DCS-4701E.

An `<img>` tag can show the mjpg source, but a `<video>` tag cannot. Nor will it when set to H.264 mode.

I've found several solutions which will open the stream in the native player, but I need it embedded.

These IP cameras also need to be secured and I don't know how to authenticate. Putting it in the `src` attribute like `http://{username}:{password}@{ip}/{whatever}` doesn't work on Android or Chrome, though it does in Firefox. That doesn't seem like good security anyway.

I've looked at some other web cam streams and on Android they either give me a direct link to an `rtsp://` to open in the native player, or the don't work at all.

So to sum up I have three problems:

1. I need to authenticate a connection to an IP camera stream.
2. I need to display that video.
3. I need to record that video.

A good solution would make it work in a `<video>` tag because then I can use video.js and plugins to record.

Thanks

Comment: Did you get any solution for this ?? i am searching for the same thing